# Realm - Adding children to a parent, then querying results on parent

Tags: swift, realm, parent-child

I'm working on how to add children to a Realm (Swift) parent and I want to query the results.

However, I'm coming up with a crash

```
do {
   let realm = try Realm()
   try realm.write {

       for locomotive in locomotives
       {
           realm.add(locomotive, update: true)
       }


       let locomotives = realm.objects(Locomotive.self)
       for locomotive in locomotives {
           print (locomotive.name)
           for _ in stride(from: 0, to: locomotive.qty, by: 1) {
               let engine : Engine = Engine.init()
               locomotive.engines.append(engine)
           }
       }

   }
} catch let error as NSError {
   //TODO: Handle error
   print(error.localizedDescription as Any)
}
```

I want to create a certain number of children, add it to the relationship

Then when I try to query it;

```
    let locomotives = realm.objects(Locomotive.self)

    print(locomotives.count)

// Find all children that are linked to this specific parent
    for loco in locomotives {
        let engines = realm.objects(Engine.self).filter("parent == \(loco)")

        print("listing engines")
        for engine in engines {
            print ("engine: \(engine.parent)")
        }
    }
```

My parent class is (at its most basic minus any mapping code)

```
class Locomotive: Object, Mappable {
    dynamic var engineid: String = ""
   var engines = List<Engine>()
}
```

My child class is:  (at its most basic minus any mapping code)

```
class Engine: Object {
    let parent = LinkingObjects(fromType: Locomotive.self, property: "engines")
}
```

This causes a crash:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "parent == Locomotive {
```

I'd like to get a list of all parent names for a given child; usually I'd do this like:

```
for each child in parent.array
{
print child.parent.name
}
```

But in realm, I do not get access to the parent's name.

How can I make queries on parent-child relationships and also a similar command to the above (get the parent's name attribute)?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realm `LinkingObjects` objects don't represent a single object; they represent an array of potentially multiple objects. As such, it's necessary to query to see if your object exists in that array, instead of querying for equality.

```
let engines = realm.objects(Engine.self).filter("%@ IN parent", loco)
```

Additionally, since Realm queries conform to `NSPredicate`, it's necessary to use the old-school `%@` notation, instead of Swift's inline code syntax.